# How to increment a variable in if condition

Tags: tcl

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 5} {incr i} {
    if {$node($i) < $node($i++)} {
        puts "first $i"
    }
}
```

I got error in `if` condition. Is it possible to increment `i` in if condition. If yes, how?

Comment: please edit the question properly

Comment: @Jerry: Are you sure you didn't edit the solution (`expr`) into the question by mistake? It's not clear to me why you would mark the suggested edit as not helpful either. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306242/yet-another-why-was-my-edit-rejected-question

Comment: @BoltClock My mistake. I accidentally did so.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `expr` for almost all arithmetic calculation in Tcl:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 5} {incr i} {
    if {$node($i) < $node([expr {$i+1}])} {
        puts "first $i"
    }
}
```

Note that `[expr {$i+1}]` does not change the value of `$i` but returns the sum of `$i` and 1.

`[incr i]` however changes the value of `$i` by adding 1 to it (but I don't think that's what you were looking for).